# Creating a new list and eliminate empty cells from existing list

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A           B            C           D
1    Product A      500       Product A      500
2    Product B      300       Product B      300
3    Product C      400       Product C      400
4                             Product D      600
5                             Product E      550
6    Product D      600       Product F      200
7    Product E      550       Product G      800
8
9    Product F      200
10   Product G      800
```

In **Column A** and **Column B** different Products with their sales are listed.
As you can see it can happen that there are empty cells in between the list.

In **Column C** and **Column D** I want to achieve now that the empty cells are deleted and the list of the product is shown without the empty cells.

Do you know a formula which can do this?

Comment: Why not just sort the column, it will push all the empty cells to the bottom of the list, effectively removing them.

Comment: It is a good idea but this list won't remain the same all the time. The list will be filled with new data every week so the user would always have to do the sorting new which is not very user friendly. Therefore, I would prefer a solution that does the job automatically.

Comment: Then depending on the size of your list, you will want vba that copies an pastes the data then sorts.  A formula will be an array formula, and depending on the amount of data it would eat up a lot of memory on the re-calc.

Comment: Why no just get the user to paste in the new data without spaces?

Comment: Array formula would be o.k. for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C1, copy across one column and both down to suit:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(A:A),"",ROW(A:A)-MIN(ROW(A:A))+1),ROW(A1)))
```

(entered CSE) ... then be patient.

Comment: Nice!  *(might want to wrap it in IFERROR)*

Comment: I am putting this one in my personal toolbox.

Comment: I usually just use a helper corner

Comment: Hi pnuts, thanks for the answer. It works perfectly. Maybe you also have a solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761525/creating-a-new-list-and-eliminate-empty-cells-and-cells-with-from-existing-l

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub deleteblanks()
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A1:B" & lastrow)
        .Value = .Value
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
        On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$20,SMALL((IF(LEN($A$1:$A$20),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$A$20))))),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

In **D1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$20,SMALL((IF(LEN($B$1:$B$20),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($B$1:$B$20))))),ROW(B1)),1),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some form of cyclic processing whether through an array formula (with CSE) or an array-processed function like AGGREGATE. You can minimize the calculation cycle with a couple of methods.

1. You are going to want to only reference the cells with data; full column references will slow calculation down to a crawl by referencing unnecessary blank cells.
2. An IF statement will not process the FALSE statement portion. Checking to determine if the above cell is a zero-length string and only calculating the cyclic portion of the formula is it is not means that you will only ever process one row more than absolutely necessary.

   ```
   =IF(SIGN(LEN(D1)), IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, $B:$B)))/(SIGN(LEN(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, $B:$B))))), ROW(1:1))), TEXT(,)), TEXT(,))
   ```

Fill right and down.

[image]