# Creating a new list and eliminate empty cells and cells with ="" from existing list

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A           B            C           D
1    Product A      500       Product A      500
2    Product B      300       Product B      300
3    Product C      400       Product C      400
4                             Product D      600
5    =""                      Product E      550
6    Product D      600       Product F      200
7    Product E      550       Product G      800
8    =""
9    Product F      200
10   Product G      800
```

In **Column A** and **Column B** different products with their sales are listed. As you can see it can either happen that there are `empty cells` or cells with `=""` in the list.

In **Column C** and **Column D** I want to achieve now that both the `empty cells` and the cells with `=""` are deleted and the list of the product is shown without the `empty cells` and without `=""`.

In order to eliminate the `empty cells` I used this formula so far:

```
={INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(A:A),"",ROW(A:A)-MIN(ROW(A:A))+1),ROW(A1)))}
```

How can I add the additional criteria `exclude =""` to this formula in order to ignore the cells with `=""` and get the list as seen in **Column C** and **Column D**.

Comment: Either Gary's Student or Jeeped's answer will do this from your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760448/creating-a-new-list-and-eliminate-empty-cells-from-existing-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(LEN(A:A)=0,"",ROW(A:A)-MIN(ROW(A:A))+1),ROW(A1)))
```

in C1 copied across one column and the pair down to suit, with CSE entry.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi pnuts, do you have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008125/list-items-based-on-criterias-in-two-different-columns