# List items based on criteria in two different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A           B            C        

1     Product      Sales        List      

2    Product A      500       Product A
3    Product B                Product C
4    Product C      400       Product D
5                             Product E  
6    =""                      Product F
7    Product D      600       Product H
8    Product E      550       
9    =""
10   Product F      200
11   Product G      =""
12   Product H      800
```

In **Column A** and **Column B** different products with their sales are listed. As you can see it can either happen that there are `empty cells` or cells with `=""` in both **Column A** or **Column B**.

In **Column C** I want to achieve now that only the products which do **NOT** have an `empty cells` or cells with `=""` in **Column A** or **Column B** are included in the list.

I could already make it work for **Column A** with this formula:

```
={INDEX($A$2:$A$100,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$100)=0,"",ROW($A$2:$A$100)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$100))+1),ROW(A1)))}
```

What do I have to change in this formula to also exclude the products which have an `empty cell` or a cell `=""` in **Column B** from my list in **Column C**?

Comment: When you have `=""` in your sample data above, do the cells actually hold a text value of `=""` *or* is it really just `""` in the cell (a zero-length string)?

Comment: It will be an ="" because later I might use an IF-formula like this IF(Cell=X,CellValue,"") to keep the cell blank in case the condition (in this case X) is not met.

Answer (score 0):

When you have worked it out for **Column A**, it is very simple to do for B:

Each cell in **Column D** has the appropriate function: (Example for D2)

`=VLOOKUP(D2, $A:$B, 2, 0)`

**NOTE:** This assumes you don't have repeated values in Column A

Answer (score 0):

doesn't have to be an array formula. use this formula in C instead.

```
=IF(AND(A:2<>"",B:2<>""),A:2,"")
```

Then autofill the formula. Then sort column C to get all product list.

or pivot the range by column C in row box to get the distinct product list in case A has duplicate products.